# Sharepoint restful api: json return value is structured differently between simialr scripts

Tags: 2010, javascript, rest, json

I have some odd behaviour when using REST API to query SharePoint lists. In one example, I have to use data.d.results[0] to get to the data, in another I have to use data.d[0]

When I use data.d[0], the example below returns: {"results":[{metadata...

```
var url = "../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ProjectStatusReport?$select=PlannedActivities,Accomplishments,PMComments&$orderby=PeriodEndDate desc&$top=1";
$.getJSON(url,function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data.d));
```

In the other one (below), data.d[0] returns: [{metadata...

```
var url = "../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ProjectDetails?$select=BusinessGoals,ProjectDocumentUrl&top=1";
$.getJSON(url,function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data.d));
```

Notice the lack of "results" in the data object of the second example. Not sure why this inconsistency. I thought it was the $orderby so I took it out but ended up with the same result.

I suspect one method, the one with results, thinks there is multiple rows of data while the other does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time that the query will return a response with a `results` is if your query does not contain `$top`. There is an error in your second code sample (`Url&top`), so I suspect that you've actually mixed up the examples. But the second code block should be the one that receives a response with the `results` object.

Comment: You were right. The reason I was getting the result object was because my top parameter was missing the $ ($top=1). Thanks!

Comment: Always a pleasure to help a fellow user of `ListData.svc`!